In OpenMP (C/C++), what is the initial private array of each thread when array reduction is to be applied?
OpenMP-4.5 supports reduction of raw arrays reduction(+:array[:]), analogous to previous scalar reduction reduction(+:scalar).
There is plenty of information on how a scalar to be reduced can be initialized privately for each thread (things like omp_priv and omp_orig), but I cannot find much on the initialization of private arrays.
I wonder whether the private array of each thread is initialized as
(a) a copy of the original array defined above the parallel block or
(b) an all-zero array?

It depends on the reduction type.
For addition, the initial array is all-zero.
For multiplication, the initial array is all-one.
The choice of the initial array probably follows Table 2.11 of https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html, just like scalar reduction.
If this is not what you want, you can also declare your own reduction strategy with the keywords omp_out, omp_in, omp_priv and omp_orig.
The directives such as omp_priv=omp_orig seem to be applied to each element of the array as an individual scalar.
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

#define NTHREADS 2
#define SIZE 3
#define NLOOPS 4

int main(){

    int* array = new int[SIZE];
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) array[i] = i;
    // Initial array 0 1 2

    // Addition 
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:array[:SIZE]) num_threads(NTHREADS)
    for ( int iiter = 0; iiter < NLOOPS ; iiter++ )
        #pragma omp critical
        for ( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
            std::cout << array[j];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // 000000000000

    // Multiplication
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(*:array[:SIZE]) num_threads(NTHREADS)
    for ( int iiter = 0; iiter < NLOOPS ; iiter++ )
        #pragma omp critical
        for ( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
            std::cout << array[j];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // 111111111111

    // User-defined reduction
    #pragma omp declare reduction(MySum: int: omp_out += omp_in) initializer(omp_priv = 2 * omp_orig)
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(MySum:array[:SIZE]) num_threads(NTHREADS)
    for ( int iiter = 0; iiter < NLOOPS ; iiter++ )
        #pragma omp critical
        for ( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ )
            std::cout << array[j];
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // 024024024024

    return 0;
}

Tested on GCC-8.3.0 and ICC-19.1.1.217.

Don't ask questions to only self-answer them. Specially not when the initial question does not meet SO guidelines.

@PepijnKramer I met this problem and couldn't find an existing answer online. So I figured it out myself and share it with the "Answer your own question" button so that someone else may find it useful. Is this conduct discouraged? If so, perhaps the "Answer your own question" button should be removed.

No self answering is ok, but the original question is not clear enough. SO usually requires you to provide a minimum reprodicuble exmple. Eg. you should have shown some code already in your question.  There are many ways an "array" can be modeled.  E.g. your array should could have been an std::vector<int> (which is better then calling new/delete yourself), or just an std::array<int,SIZE> (since SIZE is not so big)

@PepijnKramer This is a good point. I will modify my question on your advice. Thanks.

@PepijnKramer Looking at your profile you seem to lack OpenMP credentials. If you had, you'd know that the arrary could never be a std::vector. So your comment is beside the point. I consider this to be an interesting question. Please unclose it.
